# why is PHP_EOL adding a strange character?

Tags: php, row, line, rows

I have a simple multi-line textarea with this value:

```
50
20
10
```

After the form is sending I use PHP to validate the post, like this:

```
foreach( explode( PHP_EOL, $_POST['mytexarea'] ) as $row ) { 
 var_dump( $row );  
 // if( !is_numeric( $row ) ) { echo('error');} // it return 'error'!!!
}
```

that return:

```
string(3) "50" 
string(3) "20"
string(2) "10"
```

**Why in the first 2 values there are 3 characters instead of 2? What's wonrg?**

if i copy the code above in word (microsoft office) this is the result:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/kd1t8h.jpg

Comment: There seems to be a break in the 50 and a space in the 20. Try `trim()`

Comment: PHP_EOL is the line ending for the server (`"\n"` on Linux).... if your multi-line text area input string has Windows line endings (`"\r\n"`) then your explode will leave `"\r"` at the end of your values 50 and 20.... as shown by the string length for those entries.... use a trim() on the values before testing them for numeric, etc

Comment: probably because of the line break represented by `\n` that is being interpreted as a character

Comment: @MarkBaker I think that in Windows EOL is `\r\n` not `\n\r`.

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl with trim() the validation works, but I really want to understand why this is happening

Comment: @MarkBaker yes I think that's the problem, I have a linux hosting but i use WIndows as OS , there is a workaround that work with every hosting/OS instead of PHP_EOL?

Comment: trim() removes leading and trailing `"\r"` from the string being trimmed